# SQLite stores value as -1 for one column, but other columns are fine

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my application recently I've added new column `SUB_CATEGORY_ID` to my existing table **transactions**. After I insert record with `sub_category_id` value as any integer, when I queried the table and checked it returns value as -1 for `sub_category_id` rest of the columns are fine. I checked value for `sub_category_id` before inserting it is not null and having integer values like 1,2,... But still it is saving the value as -1.

Any suggestions. Please find my code below.

Code to add Transaction:

```
public int addTransaction(int categoryId, int subCategoryId, int accountId, double amount,
                          String notes, String trxType, String subTrxType, int sourceTrxId) {

    Log.d("addTransaction", "before addTransaction "+subCategoryId);
    int flag=0;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(CATEGORY_ID_COL, categoryId);
    contentValues.put(ACCOUNT_ID_COL, accountId);
    contentValues.put(AMOUNT_COL, amount);
    contentValues.put(DUE_DATE_COL, getDateTime());
    contentValues.put(CREATION_DATE, getDateTime());
    contentValues.put(NOTES_COL, notes);
    contentValues.put(TRANSACTION_TYPE_COL, trxType);
    contentValues.put(TRANSACTION_SUB_TYPE_COL, subTrxType);
    contentValues.put(SOURCE_TRX_ID_COL, sourceTrxId);
    contentValues.put(SUB_CATEGORY_ID_COL, subCategoryId);
    db.insert(TRANSACTIONS_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    flag=1;
    return flag;
}
```

Code to query transaction records returns -1 for sub_category_id column:

```
    String selectQuery1 = "SELECT TRX."+CATEGORY_ID_COL+", TRX."+SUB_CATEGORY_ID_COL+" from "+TRANSACTIONS_TABLE_NAME
            +" AS TRX ORDER BY DATETIME(TRX."+CREATION_DATE+") DESC LIMIT 50";
Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(selectQuery1, null);
    if(c1.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Log.d("fetchAllTrx", " CetgId="+c1.getLong(0)+" 
subcatgid="+c1.getLong(1));
        }while (c1.moveToNext());
    }
    c1.close();
```

Comment: Please uninstall the old application and install new one in debug mode when you do any changes in database

Answer (score 1):

A trap that many fall into at first, is assuming that the `onCreate` method runs every time and that changing the schema (adding/removing table or columns) can be implemented by just changing the SQL used to create the tables.

**The `onCreate` method only runs automatically when the database is created.** So such changes will not normally be made.

The easiest way to implement such schema changes is to either delete the App's data or uninstall the app.  A third, simple way, **if the `onUpgrade` method has been written to drop the tables and then call the onCreate method**, is to cause the `onUpgrade` method to run by increasing the database version number.

Note that all three of the above methods will result in the loss of data.
The first two delete the database causing it to be recreated. The database itself will not be deleted with the third, rather the specified tables are dropped (delete) and then recreated.

If loss of existing data would be an issue, then you can use the `onUpgrade` method to implement changes that preserve the data. For example, you could use the `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN your_new_column column_type` (you can use `DEFAULT value` to set the columns to default values).

> e.g.
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN mynewcolumn TEXT DEFAULT 'nothing as yet'
> ```
>
> would Add a column called **mynewcolumn**, with a column
>   type(affinity) of TEXT, to the table named **mytable** and all rows
>   would have the value **nothing as yet**.

Note! all the above assume that you are using a Database Helper (i.e a subclass of the SQLiteOpenHelper class ((i.e. it extends SQLiteOpenHelper))).

### Alternative issue

If you are using ALTER to add a column there are some restrictions.

You cannot add a column that has UNIQUE or PRIMARY INDEX constraints. As your column name indicates an id column then you may well have tried something like

```
String youraltersql = "ALTER TABLE "+TRANSACTIONS_TABLE_NAME+" ADD COLUMN " + SUB_CATEGORY_ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"
```

this would not work, due to INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (same if you have AUTOINCREMENT).

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

Comment: Hi Mike,Thanks for your reply. Yes I'm using database helper and I'm using OnUpgrade method only. It was working for previous changes and now database version is 4. For this column only I'm facing issue.

Comment: I've updated the answer with another potential issue based upon the name of the column and how you say it should be 1,2,..... which appears to indicate that you are trying to add a second primary index column. If not then you should edit your question to include the Databasehelper and also example output from the Logging that you've included.

Comment: Mike, I'm just adding integer column without any constraints. Also onUpgrade method exists. I've all the points you have already suggested. it seems like everything is fine. but only -1 storing in that column. I tried clean project and rebuild also but still the issue exists.

Comment: @Sundar you don't appear to have taken heed of the 2nd sentence *If not the you should edit your question......* especially the output produced by `Log.d("addTransaction", "before addTransaction "+subCategoryId);` as you appear to be saying that rows are inserted but with a value of -1 and that line shows the value being inserted into the rouge column.

Answer (score 0):

You Updated your table while adding new Column after table crated, so you have to Implement override method, have look this :

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  // If you need to add a column
  if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
     db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE "Your Table name"ADD COLUMN "new column "INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
  }
}
```